# Possibility to extend GNU Make to support non-file targets

Tags: c, makefile, scheme

I am using GNU make to manage data processing work flow, expressing dependencies for 10000+ files and 100+TB.  Now I am after a feature to express non-file targets in Makefile, such as datasets in [hdf5](https://www.hdfgroup.org/HDF5), tables in [sqlite](https://sqlite.org), (non-conventional) files in [hdfs](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/hdfs_design.html), etc.  For example:

```
# process dataset /src15 in pass1.h5 and save it as /evt15 in pass2.h5.
pass2.h5(/evt15): pass1.h5(/src15)
    ./process.py $^ -o $@
```

A close feature is [Archive Members as Targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archive-Members), but it is fairly limited,

> This construct is available only in targets and prerequisites, not in
>   recipes!

I turned to GNU make extensions, either with [C](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Loading-Objects) or [scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Guile-Integration). However, all the examples in the manual are for customizing functions. One [article](https://debian-administration.org/article/706/GNU_Make_4.0_released_including_support_for_plugins) states that

> In the future it might be possible to make more extensive plugins,
>   which would use SHA1 hashes instead of timestamps, etc. For the moment
>   though adding simple functions to Makefiles is both powerful and
>   interesting.

Therefore at least for GNU make 4.0, the extension mechanism is limited to functions.

**Question**:

1. Is it possible to define non-file targets and their recipes with the present extension mechanism of GNU make?
2. If not, any hints for hacking GNU make to achieve it?
3. If it is too complex, any drop-in replacement of GNU make to hack with?  For example, is it easier to achieve with [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net)?

Note: [drake](https://github.com/Factual/drake) has non-file targets support, but it [lacks pattern rules](https://github.com/Factual/drake/issues/41).  Writing out 10000+ recipes explicitly is tedious, even with loops.

Comment: not at all sure what your asking, however;  by using the `.PHONY` operator, any target can be declared to not result in the creation of a file.

Comment: If those files have the same extension, like: `.h5`,  then you can use the `$(wildcard: ... ) operator to get a space separated list of all the files in a directory.

Comment: user3629249, thanks.   But it is impossible to track .PHONY targets.  Each time make is invoked, everything will be made again by default.

Comment: that is not what `.PHONY` is for.  Suggest looking at the common targets `clean` and `all`  for examples of using the `.PHONY` operator.   For best help, post your `makefile` and clearly describe the problem, with possible scenarios.  Amongst other things, an existing target that is not 'out-of-date' should never be created again by make.  Note: since your make file seems to be huge, you need only post some of it.